# Imagemagick mogrify to convert images to 1:1 format and put them in a 1x1 folder in each subfolder of a directory

Tags: imagemagick

How to write code for cmd windows, using imagemagick mogrify to convert images to 1:1 format and put them in a 1x1 folder in each subfolder of a directory.

- /catalog/folder/1/1.jpg ->/catalog/folder/1/1x1/1.jpg
- /catalog/folder/2/2.jpg ->/catalog/folder/2/1x1/1.jpg
- and so on.

```
FOR /r %a IN (*.*) DO mogrify -path 1x1 -gravity center -crop "1:1" "%~a" "%~dpna.webp"
```

It works only in the main folder, but not in subfolders.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but I think you'll want to change directory into each directory you find and then run a new mogrify in each directory... something like `FOR /R %a in ??? DO ( cd %a && mogrify ... )` Try it with `( cd %a && pwd )` first.